# Clang-compiled program crashes with segfault when fsanitize=address is on

Tags: c++, clang, address-sanitizer

I created the minimal example C++ program and wanted to try out clang's address sanitizer:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compile with below it works fine.

```
c++ -g -O1 -fno-omit-frame-pointer main.cpp -o main
```

When I compile with the sanitize flag on, I get a segmentation fault.

```
c++ -g -O1 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address main.cpp -o main
```

My clang version is:

```
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

I am using **libstdc++11** (the GCC standard library implementation):
version *GLIBCXX_3.4.30* and *GLIBC_2.4*

I also have the strace here:

```
... // before this line, there are many other similar lines that document finding the other .so libraries (like the libstdc++ for example)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=47472, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 49384, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fa6b5e65000
mmap(0x7fa6b5e67000, 28672, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fa6b5e67000
mmap(0x7fa6b5e6e000, 8192, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x9000) = 0x7fa6b5e6e000
mmap(0x7fa6b5e70000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xa000) = 0x7fa6b5e70000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b5e63000
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b5e60000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fa6b5e607c0) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7fa6b5e60a90)         = 52936
set_robust_list(0x7fa6b5e60aa0, 24)     = 0
rseq(0x7fa6b5e61160, 0x20, 0, 0x53053053) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5a15000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5e70000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5e87000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5eab000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5ea5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5eeb000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5bfb000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5e9d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5ec1000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5ef0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5ef5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5f17000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5ffe000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b5e1b000, 45056, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fa6b6225000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55fb938db000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b5e5e000
mprotect(0x7fa6b6278000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7fa6b6229000, 85399)           = 0
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/home/ivan/Documents/Clang/main", 4096) = 31
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b6277000
open("/proc/self/cmdline", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "./main\0", 4096)               = 7
read(3, "", 4089)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fa6b6277000, 4096)            = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b6277000
open("/proc/self/environ", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/"..., 4096) = 4096
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fa6b6277000, 4096)            = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b623c000
open("/proc/self/environ", O_RDONLY)    = 3
read(3, "BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/"..., 8192) = 4715
read(3, "", 3477)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b623a000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b6238000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b6236000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b6277000
open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY)       = 3
read(3, "55fb937c9000-55fb937e7000 r--p 0"..., 4096) = 3985
read(3, "7fa6b5e8a000-7fa6b5e8e000 r--p 0"..., 111) = 111
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fa6b6277000, 4096)            = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b6234000
open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY)       = 3
read(3, "55fb937c9000-55fb937e7000 r--p 0"..., 8192) = 3985
read(3, "7fa6b5e8a000-7fa6b5e8e000 r--p 0"..., 4207) = 4059
read(3, "7fa6b5ef7000-7fa6b5ef9000 rw-p 0"..., 148) = 148
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fa6b6234000, 8192)            = 0
mmap(NULL, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b6232000
open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY)       = 3
read(3, "55fb937c9000-55fb937e7000 r--p 0"..., 16384) = 3985
read(3, "7fa6b5e8a000-7fa6b5e8e000 r--p 0"..., 12399) = 4059
read(3, "7fa6b5ef7000-7fa6b5ef9000 rw-p 0"..., 8340) = 2706
read(3, "", 5634)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b6277000
open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY)       = 3
read(3, "55fb937c9000-55fb937e7000 r--p 0"..., 4096) = 3985
read(3, "7fa6b5e8a000-7fa6b5e8e000 r--p 0"..., 111) = 111
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fa6b6277000, 4096)            = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b6230000
open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY)       = 3
read(3, "55fb937c9000-55fb937e7000 r--p 0"..., 8192) = 3985
read(3, "7fa6b5e8a000-7fa6b5e8e000 r--p 0"..., 4207) = 4059
read(3, "7fa6b5ef7000-7fa6b5ef9000 rw-p 0"..., 148) = 148
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fa6b6230000, 8192)            = 0
mmap(NULL, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b622e000
open("/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY)       = 3
read(3, "55fb937c9000-55fb937e7000 r--p 0"..., 16384) = 3985
read(3, "7fa6b5e8a000-7fa6b5e8e000 r--p 0"..., 12399) = 4059
read(3, "7fa6b5ef7000-7fa6b5ef9000 rw-p 0"..., 8340) = 2706
read(3, "", 5634)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fa6b622e000, 16384)           = 0
mmap(NULL, 3727360, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fa6b5472000
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=NULL} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
[1]    52933 segmentation fault (core dumped)  strace ./main
```

I am pretty new to this, and not sure where to start looking. If any of you more experienced can advise me where to start digging, I would be grateful.

Comment: Sounds like you're linking against the wrong/incompatible version of libstdc. libstdc is for gcc, not clang.

Comment: It does not work with the gcc standard library at all, or just not with this version that I have?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik clang is quite capable of using libstdc++

Comment: How did you install clang?

Comment: Just with sudo apt-get install clang-14

Comment: Which os and version? Have you installed any other libraries?

Comment: I am on a x86_64 maschine with 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-UbuntuI and I also have installed the gcc compiler but set clang as the default.

Comment: Try use of `-stdlib=libc++`, it may need to install `libc++-14-dev`.

Comment: Ignore the comments about `libstdc++` -- they are wrong -- Clang by default uses `libstdc++` and there is absolutely no problem with using it.

Comment: "I am using ... GLIBC_2.4" -- that seems unlikely to be true: `GLIBC-2.4` is from 2006. If you really are using such an old GLIBC version, that might explain the crash -- AddressSanitizer was probably never tested on such an old GLIBC.

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows, clang 17, installed using choco

Comment: For a comprehensive list of troubleshooting instructions check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77548905/1459061