# AddressSanitizer randomly throws SIGSEGV with no explanation

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault, gdb, address-sanitizer

### Project

I have a game project in C++ that I'm currently developing.
I compile every source file with `-g3 -std=c++2a -Wall ... -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak` to check for leaks and Segfaults

### The main problem

The problem is, randomly (1 in 5 times), asan (address or leak), terminates the program before reaching main with a SIGSEGV without any diagnostics.

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==28573==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x625505a4ce68 (pc 0x7cc52585f38f bp 0x000000000000 sp 0x7fff63949020 T0)
==28573==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer: nested bug in the same thread, aborting.
```

The address the SEGV happens on is always different, as is the pc (except for the last 3 digits, e68, 38f respectively)

### The system it runs on

My machine is `Arch Linux 6.7.0-arch3-1` and I'm using `g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20230801`, `GNU gdb (GDB) 13.2`, that are the latest on the repositories at the moment of writing

### What I've tried

I have no idea how to hunt down this bug, nor what might be causing it.

#### In code

I am sure the problems happens before main since printing something (with cout or printf) has no effect, same for using a signal handler, `signal(SIGSEGV, &handle);`

#### asan is part of it

Without asan the SEGV does not happen. (I have tried 50~ times and the program started correctly every time)

#### gdb

Using gdb with the program compiled with asan and ASLR turned off caused the SIGSEGV and the automatic catch

#### assembly instruction of the problem

Given the strange pattern of addresses that the problem happens on I tried using a watchpoint on any `$pc` ending with 38f (`watch ((size_t)$pc & 0xfff) == 0x38f`).
The watchpoint works, the address in question is contained in a libc function (`do_lookup_x` or similar) that is seemingly called thousands of times, before the main begins, making debugging this way practically a nightmare.

### The question

I would like to ask if anybody has any idea on how to get more information out of asan, gdb, or any other tool, because at this moment I do not have enough information to know where the problem happens or even if the problem is mine or not.

---

### Updates

@marekR and @eljay suggested some kind of symbol collision with some glibc function / names. Most of my definitions are enclosed in a namespace (thus also name mangled) and the only functions generic enough to collide with some other name are `init()`, `loop()`, and `terminate()`. Changing their name did not solve the issue

Following @ÖöTiib suggestion i tested my git history with `git bisect`, this problem present itself since the first commit, back in 2019, this means that it might have gone unnoticed all of this time, (I'm the only working on this project but seems unlikely), this is a combination of factors local to my machine, or something else

Comment: Try only address sanitizer without the leak sanitizer, just in case. I think the former implies the latter.

Comment: Does replacing `-g3` (*maximum debug info*) with `-g` (*default debug info*) make a difference?

Comment: I had similar issue some time ago. I do not remember details, but this was caused by linking issue some symbol in global scope was in conflict with C library symbol leading to crash before `main` was reached. Sadly there was no warnings from compiler or linker about issue.

Comment: @MarekR, This might be very interesting, how can I check for this problem?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat and Eljay I have tried both and the result does not change.

Comment: @MarekR • local symbols in your `.o` files take precedence over symbols in static libraries (`.a`) or shared object (`.so`).  So you can provide your own (say) `malloc`/`free` (and `calloc`, `realloc`, et al) that all the code uses.  It is very useful when intentional, and very frustrating when accidental.

Comment: @Leonard This was couple years ago, I can't recall exact details. Also I'm not sure if your issue is same. I can give you just this kind of hint.

Comment: Can you use a divide-and-conquer approach, by eliminating half-the-stuff until the problem goes away, then reintroduce that last known bad, and repeat, until you've whittled it down to the problem bit of code?  (Could be an **order of initialization** problem...?  Global statics have no guaranteed initialization order, so use-before-initialize can be intermittent.)

Comment: @eljay this could be a nice approach, but it's not easy to just remove code and recompile any project. I might do this if nothing comes out of this.

Comment: If you decide to do that, try `git bisect` (or equivalent if you are not using git). I also strongly doubt it is static initialization fiasco, or ODR violation due to e.g. using two versions of the same header-only library.

Comment: LSAN cannot work under ptrace (gdb and alike) but once you turn off LSAN you should be able to use it with gdb and do a `catch`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou and Eljay, now that you mention it I have a quite sizable header file where I declare a lot of global variables (my next step in the project was to rework this..) It contains mostly simple variables (int, floats, etc, ) but there is quite the amount of `C arrays`, some `std::vectors` and `std::vector<std::vector>`. But this has been the case for a long time and asan only started giving problems now.

Comment: Basic idea is not to search or expect us to give to you issues in gdb or asan, there can be are issues but the reasons are on 99% of cases within your program. So focus on it, it is on 99% of cases its fault. Look at it in very paranoid way like it is written by your worst enemy.  Why it is hard to eliminate code from it and to rebuild and rerun? Has the program always been unstable when built like that? Do you have global or static variables that create threads?  Did you just now start to try it with sanitizers? Are you using external dependencies? Are these also built with such options?

Comment: @ÖöTiib I am quite secure that the error is on my part, I just want to know where it is and why it only appears if asan is involved. To answer your questions, it's no particularly hard to remove code, just time consuming and my objective right now is to get more info from asan. No the program has not been like this before. I have global and static variables but they don't create threads. I've been using the sanitizer for quite a while in this project and never had this problem. I am using an external library (raylib) that is not built with asan.

Comment: But how it is supposed to be time consuming? If the issue only very recently started then git bisect will be rather short.

Comment: @ÖöTiib You are right, git bisect made things quite faster than i expected. The problem is present since the first commit, back in 2019. This means that 1. The issue has always been there and I've never noticed, or 2. It's a problem with my current system

Comment: Switching to a different tool like valgrind instead of asan might help too.

Comment: `SEGV on unknown address 0x625505a4ce68 (pc 0x7cc52585f38f bp 0x000000000000 sp 0x7fff63949020 T0)` This can happen on attempt to read or execute the address of an unloaded shared library. It usually happens on app exit, but you say it happens before reaching main, it may be not your case.

Comment: "I have no idea how to hunt down this bug ..." -- start by running your executable under GDB. If you can catch the crash under GDB, use `where` command. If you can't, try re-enabling ASLR (GDB disables it by default) with `set disable-randomization off`. Also, disabling randomization with `setarch -R ...` may produce a more consistent crash outside of GDB.

Comment: Additional info at crash point: `info locals`. Also, what version of GLIBC are you using? P.S. debugging this by a comment thread is unlikely to be productive. You should try to create an MCVE and file a bug in AddressSanitizer bug tracker.

Comment: You have the wrong attribution for `git bisect`, but I'm glad that you are at least making some progress. How big is your initial commit? How many external libs is it using? Because that's the only thing associated with `dlsym`s

Comment: [An extremely simple program triggers an 'unhandled instruction' error when compiled with sanitizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77557718/an-extremely-simple-program-triggers-an-unhandled-instruction-error-when-compi) and [Clang-compiled program crashes with segfault when fsanitize=address is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77544209/clang-compiled-program-crashes-with-segfault-when-fsanitize-address-is-on?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @EmployedRussian I was capable of track down the bug origin. Since this was the point of this question I'd close this Post.

I will try to solve the bug myself and, in case, open another question / bug tracker on asan if I'm not capable.

I any case thank you for helping me.

For anyone interested, compiling the binary with `-fsanitize=address` and running it under `gdb` with `set disable-radomization off` can cause the SIGSEGV, gdb should catch it automatically.

I'd consider this question closed.

Answer (score 1):

C instead of c++, same kernel (6.7.0-arch3-1) and same behaviour with -fsanitize=address:

> ## AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
>
> ==123687==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x62a50d774e78 (pc 0x7f62b3d5338f bp 0x000000000000 sp 0x7ffdf31e6480
> T0)
> ==123687==The signal is caused by a READ memory access. AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL AddressSanitizer: nested bug in the same
> thread, aborting.

No problems when compiled without fsanitize
I guess it isn't our fault. It must be something related to glibc/fsanitize or similar..
p.s.:Thank god I found your post. I have spent the last two hours checking commits from the last month. After this I tried the same program with those cflags in macOS and it doesn't throw any SEGV errors. I haven't tried any other linux distros though.

This is the backtrace I obtain with gdb with the tips you shared:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  do_lookup_x (undef_name=undef_name@entry=0x7c00b973e6d8 "_thread_db_sizeof_pthread",
    new_hash=new_hash@entry=3872132951, old_hash=old_hash@entry=0x7ffc4c9abbe8, ref=0x0,
    result=result@entry=0x7ffc4c9abbf0, scope=<optimized out>, i=0, version=0x0, flags=3,
    skip=<optimized out>, type_class=0, undef_map=<optimized out>) at dl-lookup.c:405
#1  0x00007c00b9e240b8 in _dl_lookup_symbol_x (undef_name=0x7c00b973e6d8 "_thread_db_sizeof_pthread",
    undef_map=<optimized out>, ref=0x7ffc4c9abc78, symbol_scope=<optimized out>, version=0x0,
    type_class=0, flags=3, skip_map=0x0) at dl-lookup.c:793
#2  0x00007c00b957300e in do_sym (handle=<optimized out>,
    name=0x7c00b973e6d8 "_thread_db_sizeof_pthread",
    who=0x7c00b96fffb3 <__sanitizer::ThreadDescriptorSize()+35>, vers=vers@entry=0x0,
    flags=flags@entry=2) at dl-sym.c:146
#3  0x00007c00b9573331 in _dl_sym (handle=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>, who=<optimized out>)
    at dl-sym.c:195
#4  0x00007c00b94a6ae8 in dlsym_doit (a=a@entry=0x7ffc4c9abee0) at dlsym.c:40
#5  0x00007c00b9e1b4e1 in __GI__dl_catch_exception (exception=exception@entry=0x7ffc4c9abe40,
    operate=0x7c00b94a6ad0 <dlsym_doit>, args=0x7ffc4c9abee0) at dl-catch.c:237
#6  0x00007c00b9e1b603 in _dl_catch_error (objname=0x7ffc4c9abe98, errstring=0x7ffc4c9abea0,
    mallocedp=0x7ffc4c9abe97, operate=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at dl-catch.c:256
#7  0x00007c00b94a64f7 in _dlerror_run (operate=operate@entry=0x7c00b94a6ad0 <dlsym_doit>,
    args=args@entry=0x7ffc4c9abee0) at dlerror.c:138
#8  0x00007c00b94a6b75 in dlsym_implementation (dl_caller=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>,
    handle=<optimized out>) at dlsym.c:54
#9  ___dlsym (handle=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>) at dlsym.c:68
#10 0x00007c00b96fffb3 in __sanitizer::ThreadDescriptorSize ()
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_linux_libcdep.cpp:298
#11 0x00007c00b97017ae in __sanitizer::ThreadDescriptorSize ()
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_linux_libcdep.cpp:294
#12 __sanitizer::GetTls (size=0x7ffc4c9abfb8, addr=0x7c00b9dfa040)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_linux_libcdep.cpp:498
#13 __sanitizer::GetThreadStackAndTls (main=true, stk_addr=stk_addr@entry=0x7c00b9dfa020,
    stk_size=stk_size@entry=0x7ffc4c9abfc0, tls_addr=tls_addr@entry=0x7c00b9dfa040,
    tls_size=tls_size@entry=0x7ffc4c9abfb8)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_linux_libcdep.cpp:595
#14 0x00007c00b96f0ff4 in __asan::AsanThread::SetThreadStackAndTls (this=this@entry=0x7c00b9dfa000,
    options=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_thread.h:77
#15 0x00007c00b96f14ee in __asan::AsanThread::Init (this=this@entry=0x7c00b9dfa000,
    options=options@entry=0x0) at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_thread.cpp:234
#16 0x00007c00b96f19e5 in __asan::AsanThread::ThreadStart (this=this@entry=0x7c00b9dfa000,
    os_id=130231) at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_thread.cpp:264
#17 0x00007c00b96f2604 in __asan::CreateMainThread ()
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_thread.cpp:295
#18 0x00007c00b96ee9df in __asan::AsanInitInternal ()
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_rtl.cpp:480
#19 0x00007c00b9e1f02a in _dl_init (main_map=0x7c00b9e4e2d0, argc=1, argv=0x7ffc4c9ac0c8,
    env=0x7ffc4c9ac0d8) at dl-init.c:122
```

> ```
> init.c 
> 121   signal(SIGINT, ft_sig_handler);
> 122   signal(SIGQUIT, ft_sig_handler);
> ```

makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

(I know this isn't an answer, exactly, but I couldn't post it as a comment)

If we are seeing the same issue, which appears to be the case judging by its spurious nature and the non-typical asan output, I'm pretty sure the bug is not in your code. This program exhibits the same behaviour (crash ~ every 5 times, all fine without asan and valgrind also says nothing):

```cpp
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array p {1, 2};
    for (auto i : p) { }
}
```

compiled with `g++ test.cpp -std=c++20 -fsanitize=address` running the executable a few times produces:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==38449==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x6212e1c61e78 (pc 0x779949c4638f bp 0x000000000000 sp 0x7fff726381e0 T0)
==38449==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer: nested bug in the same thread, aborting.
```

My system: Arch Linux, kernel 6.6.12-1-lts, g++ (GCC) 13.2.1 20230801

P.S.

Forgot to mention, this does appear to happen with clang (clang version 16.0.6, using libstdc++)

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same issue; simply downgrade the kernel.
I'm not sure why, but it seems that asan doesn't get along with the current version. After running the following command and a quick reboot, everything returned to normal:
`pacman -Udd file:///var/cache/pacman/pkg/linux-headers-6.6.10.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst file:///var/cache/pacman/pkg/linux-6.6.10.arch1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst`
Replace "6.6.10.arch1-1" in both files with the version you wish to downgrade to and it should do the trick.

Comment: Downgrading the kernel and sticking to an old version for all eternity is hardly a proper fix for a bug in a piece of software.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you may encounter problems with dependencies, such as Nvidia drivers, when you downgrade. Therefore, make sure that you have a bootable backup, so you can also downgrade the drivers if needed.