# Possible Bug in GCC Sanitizers?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, sanitizer

I always compile my programs with `gcc` and during development always with:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c2x -fsanitize=address,undefined
```

Today I noticed that the address sanitizer randomly detects SEGVs in my program. I couldn't find the error, so I pretty much just removed everything (thought I might have gotten the c23 stuff wrong, as I haven't touched that in a few months) and removed the `undefined sanitizer`.

The issue still persisted.

Then I tried compiling with clang and the issue was gone (at least for 10000 runs on my machine). So I guess something is wrong with GCC? Or I have some weird error in my code (but I highly doubt that given the code below). Can anyone reproduce this, or point out the error I made?

Makefile:

```
gcc: main.c
        gcc main.c -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c2x -fsanitize=address

clang: main.c
        clang main.c -g -Wall -Wextra -std=c2x -fsanitize=address
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) { return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..1000}; do
    echo $i
    ./a.out 2>> log.log
done
```

error:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==26035==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x62f205f20e78 (pc 0x7d61693e138f bp 0x000000000000 sp 0x7ffc6f41b390 T0)
==26035==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer: nested bug in the same thread, aborting.
```

GCC and clang version:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 16.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 13.2.1 20230801
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTAB`ITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

**Update 1:**

The issue persisted on another machine, same OS, same version of GCC and clang, but different Kernel.
OS: `Arch Linux`
Kernel:

- Original Machine: `6.7.1-arch1-1`
- Second Machine: `6.7.0-arch3-1`

Comment: Does not immediately fall over at https://godbolt.org/z/cEerax5zx . Have you tried the binary on a different machine? Maybe some library is corrupted. Or you can try running memcheck to rule out hardware issues.

Comment: I updated the OP with additional information; tldr: Issue persisted on another machine. I am not really sure how to run Valgrind's memcheck as valgrind does not work combined with ASAN. Is there another memcheck I am not aware of?

Comment: Can't reproduce with `gcc (GCC) 13.2.1 20231205 (Red Hat 13.2.1-6)`, Fedora 39, kernel `6.6.12-200.fc39.x86_64`.  I wonder if it could be a bug in Arch?

Comment: Could be a weird kernel/glibc bug, maybe a combination of things between the kernel loader and glibc that interact in the wrong way... interesting.

Comment: Currently compiling GCC 11 to try it out. Have you guys any other ideas how I might track this down?

Comment: Did you disable memory overcommit or set any other non-default kernel configuration?

Comment: I didn't configure anything manually. But maybe Arch sets some non-standard flags? Should I post the Kernel config currently running, it is kinda long. Or just the CC options at the beginning?

Comment: @ben No, the memory overcommit option is a runtime one (via /proc/sys aka sysctl interface). I am not aware of any general-use distribution disabling it by default, but it is something that ASAN requires to work properly. It does some tricks with mapping memory.

Comment: `$ cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` gives `0` so I guess it is set to false. Can I just do `$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` to change it or do I have to set that somewhere else?

Comment: @ben No, `0` is the correct setting. The problematic setting would be `2`. If you wanted to change the setting your approach would be valid, but would not survive a reboot (for that the sysctl service should be used). Alternatively there are some known issues with ASLR and ASAN. You could try disabling that as well, but that should not happen on a production system or workstation because it implies an increased security risk. But it could be any other issue as well.

Comment: @ben Also, a side note about Stackoverflow: If you want another user to be notified about your answer you need to put an `@` followed by their user name into your answer as I am doing here at the beginning of my comment. This is not necessary only when answering to the original author of the post under which the comment appears.

Comment: If you are using the linux-hardened package for the kernel, you could try the non-hardened one.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for pointing out how to answer correctly! I tested overcommit settings on my second machine (didn't want it to interfere with the gcc11 compilation). When I set it to `1` the issue persists, but it seems less frequent. When I set it to `2` the process just crashes with: `./test.sh: line 3: 18732 Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: Sorry s/memcheck/memtest86/, but if the binary crashes on another machine as well, there is no point in trying that. If you run under gdb (or examine the coredump under gdb), you may find more about where exactly it crashed.

Comment: Found another SO thread that seems to be somewhat the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77826203/addresssanitizer-randomly-throws-sigsegv-with-no-explanation although one answer says that it also seems to happen with clang, which does not seem to be the case for me.

Comment: I can reproduce this consistently in a VM with the same setup: Arch Linux 6.7.0-arch3-1 using the `Arch-Linux-x86_64-basic-20240115.207158.qcow2` image from here: https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/arch-boxes/-/packages/1294. Makes me even more suspicious that this is indeed a weird interaction between userspace glibc loader and kernel. Will need to investigate more...

Comment: @273K `void func()` is not an ellipsis function. It is a declaration, but not a function prototype. The declaration introduces the function name and its return type. A function prototype is a function declaration which also declares the parameter types. `int main(void)` is AFAIK the correct way to say: "the main function does not take in arguments" and is allowed by the standard. And the C23 standard uses it in multiple examples.

Comment: Found the culprit: it's this commit from Arch Linux kernel tree that is causing the issue https://github.com/archlinux/linux/commit/3a88b77d3cb9f9cd8a8aee052ab479b73aeb2e80. Apparently ASAN does not behave well when `ARCH_MMAP_RND_BITS` is set to `ARCH_MMAP_RND_BITS_MAX` (32). With the default value (28) it works, but Arch Linux decided to increase it recently because of... reasons that are boring to explain. So I would say it's an ASAN bug caused by this change, probably gotta look into libasan.

Answer (score 12):

**Update**: `gcc-libs` version `13.2.1-4` was just released and the issue should be fixed now, simply update the package: `pacman -S gcc-libs`.

**TL;DR**: it turns out to be a bug in libasan, which has already been fixed and will be pushed to package repositories soon. Keep `gcc-libs` up to date and the next version after `13.2.1-3` will have the fix. [Disabling ASLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5194709/3889449) may work around the issue temporarily.

Arch Linux recently applied a patch ([commit](https://github.com/archlinux/linux/commit/3a88b77d3cb9f9cd8a8aee052ab479b73aeb2e80)) to set userspace ASLR bits to the maximum value of 32 and shipped both the LTS and non-LTS kernels with this change ([commit](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/linux-lts/-/commit/de42b55679bc535116b861d993286c450a6cabef)). This was done because ASLR has been weakened/broken by Linux for a while and the issue went unnoticed [until recently](https://lists.openwall.net/linux-hardening/2024/01/15/3), so major Linux distros quickly patched and increased the ASLR bits in their kernel configs.

Having too many ASLR bits however causes issues with libasan, where high ASLR randomization breaks the ASAN allocator because it assumes less ASLR bits, reserving a memory area at an address that is too low and can collide with the randomized PIE base at runtime if the offset applied by ASLR is too high. The bug was already discovered and fixed both by libasan developers ([commit](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/fb77ca05ffb4f8e666878f2f6718a9fb4d686839)) and Arch Linux maintainers in the `gcc-libs` package that includes libasan ([commit](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/gcc/-/commit/15cbe5ecc28cc4f52a38bad5a5cecaaa8a66a020)).

The issue currently affects 6.6.11+ and 6.7.0+ Arch Linux kernels with `gcc-libs` version `13.2.1-3` and below. The new (fixed) version of `gcc-libs` still hasn't been pushed to the official Arch Linux package repositories, so we will have to wait and update `gcc-libs` when this happens.

If you cannot wait, the solution is to either downgrade your current kernel to 6.6.10 or below, or to build and install the latest `gcc-libs` package yourself. You can also try [disabling ASLR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5194709/3889449) to work around the issue temporarily (until next boot, or permanently if you do it through kernel command line with `nokaslr`, though that is not recommended as it reduces the security of your system).

---

Commit message from libasan explaining the issue:

> D147984 was reverted because it broke lit tests on Mac. This revision is based on D147984
> but maintains the old behavior for Apple.
>
> Note that, per the follow-up discussion with MaskRay in D147984, this patch excludes Apple
> but includes other platforms (e.g., aarch64, MIPS64) and OSes (e.g., FreeBSD, S390X), not just
> x86-64 Linux.
>
> Original commit message from D147984:
>
> Users have discovered [*] that when CONFIG_ARCH_MMAP_RND_BITS == 32,
> it will frequently conflict with ASan's allocator on x86-64 Linux, because the
> PIE program segment base address of 0x555555555554 plus an ASLR shift of up to
> ((2**32) * 4K == 0x100000000000) will sometimes exceed ASan's hardcoded
> base address of 0x600000000000. We fix this by simply moving the allocator base
> to 0x500000000000, which is below the PIE program segment base address. This is
> cleaner than trying to move it to another location that is sandwiched between
> the PIE program and library segments, because if either of those grow too large,
> it will collide with the allocator region.
>
> Note that we will never need to change this base address again (unless we want to increase
> the size of the allocator), because ASLR cannot be set above 32-bits for x86-64 Linux (the
> PIE program segment and library segments would collide with each other; see also
> ARCH_MMAP_RND_BITS_MAX in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/Kconfig).

Comment: As a workaround, you can also run your program with `setarch $(uname -m) -R` to disable the randomization of the virtual address space.

Comment: @Bruno that's cool. Now that you made me think about it, you can also disable ASLR in the conventional way through kernel command line or sysctl, don't know why it didn't come to mind when I was answering :')