# AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL from -fsanitize=address flag

Tags: c++, compiler-flags

Whenever I run any c++ code, regardless of its contents, I sometimes randomly get the following error:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am on Ubuntu 23.10 with kernel version: Linux 6.5.0-25-generic x86_64. Using the g++ 13.2.0 compiler. The code content really doesn't matter, a basic Hello World program causes the issue. I am compiling with the following flags: `g++ test.cpp -std=c++23 -fsanitize=address -o test`

The problem seems to come from using the following flag:

```
-fsanitize=address
```

I noticed that this only started happening when I start messing with a code with dynamic memory allocation, I also sometimes got memory leakage out of nowhere. I thought the problem will disappear when I wrote normal codes again, but that wasn't the case.

When I tried running the following command:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

And running the code again, I got a new error:

```
==18240==Shadow memory range interleaves with an existing memory mapping. ASan cannot proceed correctly. ABORTING.
==18240==ASan shadow was supposed to be located in the \[0x00007fff7000-0x10007fff7fff\] range.
==18240==This might be related to ELF_ET_DYN_BASE change in Linux 4.12.
==18240==See https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/856 for possible workarounds.
==18240==Process memory map follows:
0x0f0051f00000-0x0f0052000000   
0x0f0052100000-0x0f0052200000   
0x0f0052300000-0x0f0052400000   
0x0f0052500000-0x0f0052600000   
0x0f0052700000-0x0f0052800000   
0x0f0052872000-0x0f0052c00000   
0x0f0052c00000-0x0f0052c26000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x0f0052c26000-0x0f0052da5000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x0f0052da5000-0x0f0052dfa000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x0f0052dfa000-0x0f0052dfe000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x0f0052dfe000-0x0f0052e00000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x0f0052e00000-0x0f0052e0d000   
0x0f0053000000-0x0f005309c000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.32
0x0f005309c000-0x0f00531cd000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.32
0x0f00531cd000-0x0f005325a000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.32
0x0f005325a000-0x0f0053265000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.32
0x0f0053265000-0x0f0053268000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.32
0x0f0053268000-0x0f005326c000   
0x0f0053400000-0x0f0053425000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.8.0.0
0x0f0053425000-0x0f0053534000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.8.0.0
0x0f0053534000-0x0f0053569000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.8.0.0
0x0f0053569000-0x0f005356d000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.8.0.0
0x0f005356d000-0x0f0053570000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.8.0.0
0x0f0053570000-0x0f0053aa4000   
0x0f0053b57000-0x0f0053b6c000   
0x0f0053b6c000-0x0f0053b6f000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
0x0f0053b6f000-0x0f0053b8a000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
0x0f0053b8a000-0x0f0053b8e000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
0x0f0053b8e000-0x0f0053b8f000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
0x0f0053b8f000-0x0f0053b90000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
0x0f0053b90000-0x0f0053ba0000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
0x0f0053ba0000-0x0f0053c20000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
0x0f0053c20000-0x0f0053c79000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
0x0f0053c79000-0x0f0053c7a000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
0x0f0053c7a000-0x0f0053c7b000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
0x0f0053c82000-0x0f0053c90000   
0x0f0053c90000-0x0f0053c91000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x0f0053c91000-0x0f0053cbb000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x0f0053cbb000-0x0f0053cc5000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x0f0053cc5000-0x0f0053cc7000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x0f0053cc7000-0x0f0053cc9000   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x5e446ea4f000-0x5e446ea50000   /home/x/Desktop/test
0x5e446ea50000-0x5e446ea51000   /home/x/Desktop/test
0x5e446ea51000-0x5e446ea52000   /home/x/Desktop/test
0x5e446ea52000-0x5e446ea53000   /home/x/Desktop/test
0x5e446ea53000-0x5e446ea54000   /home/x/Desktop/test
0x7ffce680d000-0x7ffce682e000   \[stack\]
0x7ffce68d0000-0x7ffce68d4000   \[vvar\]
0x7ffce68d4000-0x7ffce68d6000   \[vdso\]
0xffffffffff600000-0xffffffffff601000   \[vsyscall\]
==18240==End of process memory map.
```

Is there someway to prevent this?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Please show a [mre]. Which OS and compiler version are you using? Which Linux kernel version?

Comment: *The problem seems to come from using the following flag: `-fsanitize=address`.* No, it comes from errors in your code. *Is there someway to prevent this?* Yes, fix errors in your code. Start with enabling compiler warnings and fix them.

Comment: @AlanBirtles What kind of debugger are you referring to? I only tried using valgrind to detect memory leaks but couldn't get to something.
I am on Ubuntu 23.10 with kernel version: Linux 6.5.0-25-generic x86_64. Using the g++ 13.2.0 compiler.
The code content really doesn't matter, a basic Hello World program causes the issue.
I am compiling with the following flags: `g++ test.cpp -std=c++23 -fsanitize=address -o test`
It's hard to give a reproducible example because I don't know what caused this to happen all of the sudden

Comment: @273K I tried running this and it still gave the same error
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << 1;
  return 0;
}

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 doesn't have [g++ 13.2.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=G%2B%2B&searchon=names&suite=mantic&section=all). When you installed it manually, you did it at your own risk and got runtime mismatches.

Comment: Typical good *g++* command for Valgrind: `g++ -g -O2 -W -Wall -std=c++23 -o test test.cpp`. Typical good *g++* command for AddressSanitizer; `g++ -fsanitize=address -g -O2 -W -Wall -std=c++23 -o test test.cpp`.

Comment: Use the default `g++` command available s part of the `g++` Ubuntu package. Copy-paste the output of `g++ -v` to your question. Copy-paste the full source code of `test.cpp` to your question. Copy-paste the full compiler command-line to your question. Copy-paste the full program output to your question. All this makes it possible for others to reproduce your results.

Comment: Maybe your Ubuntu system has incompatible compilers and libraries installed. You may want to retry in a freshly installed Ubuntu VM, and check if it works.

Comment: A debugger like GDB? https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerAndDebugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TheFortyTwo Thankyou for you post. I have the same experience. I am using sanitizer with gtest. Approximately every third time I execute the tests I get endless list AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL. I have also narrowed it down to be independent of my code.

So, I was thinking it had to be `gtest` or the sanitizer itself. I am on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, kernel 6.5.0-25-generic and gcc(Ubuntu 11.4.0~22.04) 11.4.0.

Found this post that may be the solution: [Possible Bug in GCC Sanitizers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77894856/possible-bug-in-gcc-sanitizers)

Will try to upgrade gcc-libs as suggested there.